# Override Swift UIColor Class Functions

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a "dark" mode feature for my iOS application in Swift 1.2 and am thinking about writing an extension or subclass of UIColor. I was wondering if it's possible to override UIColor.whiteColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), and other built-in colors. If not, what's a better way to accomplish a dark mode for the entire app? The following code doesn't work as an extension.

```
class func whiteColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(...)
}
```

because it conflicts with the existing declaration of whiteColor() in UIColor.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't sound like a good idea. ;-) How would you set it back to white, when whiteColor was overwritten? You'd have to store the original white somewhere. So why don't you store it in a property and name it backgroundColor or whatever it is and change it when the mode changes to "dark" or back.

Comment: it's just because the text labels and other icons need to change colors as well. For example, text labels would be black on a white background and white on a black background. This is why I'm hesitant to do that because I'd have a lot of global variables.

Comment: I see, but overwriting a color in UIColor would not update all elements on screen. They store copies in their properties. Mompl... I'll answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to write a ColorScheme class that stores your colors (say labelColor, backgroundColor, ...). When you change your ColorScheme to "dark mode", just set the new colors and push an NSNotification. Your view controller(s) should listen to it and set the colors for labels, background, etc. to the new values.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **Swift 3** answer for the "override" part of your question. The snippet below contains placeholders. It swaps the system implementation with your own.

```
extension UIColor {

    // ******************************************************************
    // MARK: - Override black with own implementation
    // ******************************************************************

    override open class func initialize() {
        if self == UIColor.self {
            let blackMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(getter: black))
            let myBlackMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(getter: myBlack))
            method_exchangeImplementations(blackMethod, myBlackMethod)

            let whiteMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(getter: white))
            let myWhiteMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(getter: myWhite))
            method_exchangeImplementations(whiteMethod, myWhiteMethod)
        }
    }

    // for a light background
    open class var myBlack: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
    }

    // for a dark background
    open class var myWhite: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
    }
}
```

The override of initialize doesn't work anymore, so I'll throw in a solution for **Swift 4**:

```
extension UIColor {

    // ******************************************************************
    // MARK: - Override black with own implementation
    // ******************************************************************

    static let classInit: Void = {
        let blackMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIColor.self, #selector(getter: black))
        let myBlackMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIColor.self, #selector(getter: myBlack))
        method_exchangeImplementations(blackMethod, myBlackMethod)

        let whiteMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIColor.self, #selector(getter: white))
        let myWhiteMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIColor.self, #selector(getter: myWhite))
        method_exchangeImplementations(whiteMethod, myWhiteMethod)
    }()

    // for a light background
    open class var myBlack: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
    }

    // for a dark background
    open class var myWhite: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
    }
}
```

You swizzle the methods right after `AppDelegate` is initialized:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        UIColor.classInit
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to write your own UIColor extensions.

With Swift 3, predefined UIColors are used accordingly:

```
var myColor: UIColor = .white // or .clear or whatever
```

Therefore, if you want something similar, such as the following...

```
var myColor: UIColor = .myCustomColor
```

...then, you would define the extension like so:

```
extension UIColor
    {
    public class var myCustomColor: UIColor
        {
        return UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
```

In fact, Apple defines white as:

```
public class var white: UIColor
```