# How do I customize SystemBackground Color in SwiftUI?

Tags: colors, swiftui

The systemBackground and systemGroupedBackground colors are fine for most situations but I have a project where I would like to customize the background - particularly for DarkMode.

The only option for any degree of modification that I have found so far is the following - which doesn't change things much.

```
extension Color {
    static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground)
    static let secondarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this (after creating the custom color in Assets):

```
static let gtSystemBG = Color("GTSystemBackground")

static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.gtSystemBG)
```

It obviously does not work. Is it possible to modify the systemBackground colors? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Swift UIColor Class Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320593/override-swift-uicolor-class-functions)

Comment: No it does not. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Making your own color in the assets folder will work, but `Color(UIColor.gtSystemBG)` won't (you defined `gtSystemBG` as a `Color`, not `UIColor`).

```
static let gtSystemBG = Color("GTSystemBackground") /// Color
static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.gtSystemBG) /// Type 'UIColor' has no member 'gtSystemBG'
```

Instead, just directly define `systemGroupedBackground` as a `Color`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.systemGroupedBackground)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

extension Color {
    static let systemGroupedBackground = Color("GTSystemBackground")
}
```

Result:

[image: Gray rectangle]

Comment: This works fine for a custom color but what I am trying to customize are the default colors for Dark Mode. I can use ZStack to color the background of a view, but as soon as I introduce a List into the view the default colors take over.

Comment: @forrest so that's what you were trying to do! However I think there's no way to override system colors. Instead, change the Lists' colors with `appearance()` - for example `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor`. For extended customization you might need [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).